# removing constness in templated function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constants, const-cast

I have a little issue with removing the constness of using Templated function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template< typename T>
void fct(T&  param)
{
  const_cast<T>(param) = 40;    
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  int x = 30;
  const int  cx = x;
  const int& rx = x;
  fct(cx);
  return 0;
}
```

when I run this I get :

> error C2440: 'const_cast' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'int'

How could I use `const_cast` into my function.

Comment: No matter the error, what you're trying to do is a ***bad idea***.

Comment: @KillzoneKid How can `T` be `int`? He's passing a `const int&`, which is matched against a `T&` so `T` is deduced to be `const int`.

Comment: @oisyn he edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const_cast<T>(param) = 40;` doesn't do what you want, for both `fct(cx);` and `fct(rx);`, `T` is deduced as `const int`.

If you want to remove the constness, i.e. get a reference to non-const, you can use [`std::remove_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv):

```
const_cast<typename std::remove_const<T>::type &>(param) = 40;
```

For `T` is deduced as `const int`, `typename std::remove_const<T>::type` results in `int`, then the above code is same as `const_cast<int &>(param)...`.

Note that `cx` is a constant, trying to modify it via reference got from `const_cast` leads to UB. For `rx` it's fine, it refers to a non-constant in fact.

Comment: Sorry, I am using C++11 :/ not 14 *

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd Revised.

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) is fine.

Comment: yes I did read that but The thing that I missed is the member type `type`.

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd That's why C++14 makes it simpler; `typename std::remove_const<T>::type` => `std::remove_const_t<T>`.

Comment: Doesn't this fail if you pass a non const to it?

Comment: @Yakk if I believe the wording and example from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv), it just leaves unqualified types untouched. Which makes sense.

Comment: @quen no: the const cast that does nothing

Comment: @Yakk [it looks fine as well](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const.cast#2) :)

Comment: @Quentin Ok; I was unsure.

Answer (score 6):

you can try to do something like this:

```
template< typename T>
void fct(const T&  param)
{
  const_cast<T&>(param) = 40;    
}
```

template type T must be a reference or your cast does not make any sense

Comment: Modifying a const object through a non-const access path is UB

Comment: Yes @AMA, but from curiousity I wanna know how to be able to remove the const ;D

Comment: Aside from the fact that the indended goal is bad, I like this answer better for its simplicity. No need for type traits, let te compiler take out the `const` of the deduced type by explicitely specifying it. Of course, the different versions don't do exactly the same: this one binds to rvalues, the other one doesn't. Which can either be a pro or a con, depending on your requirements.